# .htaccess и поддомен

Tags: .htaccess

У меня есть такое

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1&mobile=false [L,QSA]
```

Мне нужно чтобы когда пришел запрос с поддомена m.site.ru, произошло вот такое

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1&mobile=true [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.site\.ru$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?route=$1&mobile=true [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1&mobile=false [L,QSA]
```

Comment: почему-то не работает, когда переходишь по ссылке m.site.ru - выдает ошибку

Comment: все заработало, просто я - лох