# Как считать url?

Tags: url, php

Как считать URL, который сейчас в адресной строке? Т.е. чтобы если введён `domain.sitename.com`, выводилось какая-та информация, а если ввести `domain1.sitename.com` - выводилась другая информация? Оба URL ведут к одному серверу, к одному сайту, к одному файлу index.php.

И другой вопрос. Как сделать, чтобы вместо `sitename.com/profile.php` - выводилось, к примеру, `sitename.com/profile`?

Comment: сформулировать правильно вопрос.

Из того что написано, тут наверчено все что только можно, и как URL понимать и как написать .htaccess файл и редирект.

Правильно заданный вопрос - правильно полученный ответ.

Comment: Вопрос сапоставлен правильно. Я не вижу тут ничего не понятного.

Comment: "сАпоставлен"? С чем?

Comment: Я видимо НуП я не понял - к одному серверу всмысле к обоим доменам привязана папка или редирект на один адрес?

Comment: Не НуП, хотя кто его знает... Впрочем, не это важно...
2 URL'a подключены к одному сайту, и мне нужно выводить разную информацию, по разному URL'у...

Comment: Тогда гуглите "регулярные выражения".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[htaccess-и-поддомен](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/78070/htaccess-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD)

Answer (score 1):

1 `print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);`

2 создать папку profile, в ней index.php с содержимым profile.php

Comment: Насчёт 1: спасибо!
Насчёт 2: Не, мне нужен другой способ, я указал пример, на самом деле мне нужно вывести вместо: sitename.com/profile.php - это: sitename.com/id12345

Comment: [насчет 2 :)](http://hashcode.ru/questions/28221/%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%BF%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5) Либо гуглите про mod_rewrite и регулярные выражения